# Read text from Button (Tkinter)

Tags: python, list, function, tkinter, nonetype

```
BuchstabenOptionen = Toplevel()
BuchstabenOptionen.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
BuchstabenOptionen.title("Buchstabenoptionen")


def BuchstabenAuswertung():
    hallo = Button_Buchstaben['text']


listeBuchstaben = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
row_Buchstaben = 0
column_Buchstaben = 0
    
for x in listeBuchstaben:
    global text
    print(x)
    row_Buchstaben = row_Buchstaben + 1
    if row_Buchstaben == 5:
        column_Buchstaben = column_Buchstaben +1
        row_Buchstaben = 1
    
    Button_Buchstaben =  Button(BuchstabenOptionen, text = x, font = BuchstabenFont, command = BuchstabenAuswertung).grid(row = row_Buchstaben, column = column_Buchstaben, padx = "5", pady = "5")
```

Code is returning    hallo = Button_Buchstaben['text'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

What did i wrong?

Comment: Move the ```grid``` to next line. It returns ```None``` which you are trying to fetch

Answer (score 0):

All geometry managers: `pack`,`place` or `grid` return `None`. That is why it was throwing the error. So you should do something like this

```
Button_Buchstaben =  Button(BuchstabenOptionen, text = x, font = BuchstabenFont, command = BuchstabenAuswertung)
Button_Buchstaben.grid(row = row_Buchstaben, column = column_Buchstaben, padx = "5", pady = "5")
```

Also,your `Button_Buchstaben` is constantly updated to a new value. So when you click on it, only the last value will be printed. Update your function to this

```
def BuchstabenAuswertung(text):
    print(text)
```

We will create a local variable for each iteration and pass it as a parameter for the function.

```
Button_Buchstaben =  Button(BuchstabenOptionen, text = x, font = BuchstabenFont, command = lambda i=x:BuchstabenAuswertung(i))
```